# How can I change the screen resolution?

Tags: resolution, tails-os

I'm running Tails.

- Can't use the settings menu to do it, there's only one option there and it's like 600x800 which is the problem, I think
- Can't figure out what the display name is for my monitor, have tried using `w` but it tells me my console's not wide enough to do it. I cannot make the window bigger because of my screen resolution. It already looks huge.
- All the solutions I've found involve using xrandr, but I need to know the display name of my monitor to do them.

I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one of the recent nvidia cards, then it's a [known issue](https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html#index38h2) and it may be resolved by [upgrading linux kernel](https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/10298) to 4.x. Otherwise, your GPU is likely unsupported (or missing driver) and you can switch if you have this option.

Comment: Shoot. I got a new laptop & now there's tons of stuff not working, mouse doesn't work, resolution is awful, can't fix anything cause other stuff's broken lol. That sucks.

Comment: Then try **Qubes**. It's based on Fedora 23 and it's the most secure OS, too. You can run a Tails HVM on it (and many others, like Whonix). There is a workaround for original nvidia drivers as well (if preinstalled won't work for you).